# User is leaving the channel after page refresh

Tags: javascript, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

How do I rejoin to the channel after browser be refreshed.
I'm using Agora.io RTM JS to developer a chat application.
When I click f5, I leave the channel that I was before

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify how you're initially connecting to the channel. On your page load you should re-execute your channel join function to reconnect your client.

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks